# How do I eliminate "name error" when closing a file that I opened in another function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, fclose

W_A11, 2000-02, Moving average, 59.66666667, 50.92582302, 68.40751031, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,

W_A11, 2001-03, Moving average, 60, 51.23477459, 68.76522541, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,

W_A11, 2002-04, Moving average, 59, 50.30812505, 67.69187495, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,

```
def append_to_datalist(): #Datalist should be called append_to_datafile0, 
                          #change that for the next program

       """Append_to_datalist (should be datafile) first wipes the outfile 
          clean then appends all read lines containing the
          same year specified in querydate() from the infile to the 
          outfile"""

    outfile = open("datalist.csv", "w") #these two lines are for resetting 
                                         #the file so it remains manageably 
                                         #small
    outfile.write('')                   #this is the second line
    outfile = open("datalist.csv", "a")
    next(infile)
# extract data
    for line in infile:
        linefromfile = line.strip('\n').split(',')
        tuple1 = tuple(linefromfile)
        outfile.write('\n' + str(tuple1))
    outfile.close()

def openfile_and_append_to_datalist():
    # input for file name
    filename = input(
    "Please enter the name of the file, including the file extension, from 
     which we will be extracting data"
    " ex)injury_statistics.txt ")

    # open infile
    infile = open(filename, "r")

    # append infile data to outfile
    append_to_datalist()

    # close infile
    infile.close()

openfile_and_append_to_datalist()
```

When I run this file it runs fine until it tries closing the infile, then it returns "name error 'infile' is not defined."

I am unsure what to try besides unnesting append_to_datalist() from openfile_and_append_to_datalist() which I tried unsuccessfully.

The reason that my question says infile is open in another function is because append_to_datalist() uses infile.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting (some of the indents look wrong) and cut it back to a representative example of your problem. An easy place to start is cutting commented-out code, and removing the `querydate` function, which isn't called elsewhere in your code. Smaller is better. This will help people successfully answer your question.

Comment: querydate is used by append to datalist's forloop. I will edit the code now.

Comment: Thanks! I see `querydate` mentioned in the comments, but I still can't find a usage in the code anywhere.

Comment: If you call the function "querydate()" and you use "querydate" in the function then the function returns and address reference. I called it "qdate" for when it is being referenced later in the code.

Comment: What I mean is that your question pertains to `openfile_and_append_to_datalist()`, and to `append_to_datalist()`. The `querydate()` function may part of your program, but it's not used in your example, and doesn't seem to pertain to your problem, which relates to `infile`.

Comment: I edited the post as you requested and am now verifying your answer in pycharm.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it much easier to read through.

Comment: This question is now fully resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not with *closing* `infile`, but rather with its use in the `append_to_datalist()` function. The `NameError` exception is correct in telling you that `infile` is not defined, because in that function, it *isn't* defined. It's only defined in the scope of `openfile_and_append_to_datalist()`.

In order to reference `infile` from `append_to_datalist()`, you will need to pass it as a function argument. First change your function definition:

```
def append_to_datalist(infile):
    ...
```

And then pass `infile` when you call the function:

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
append_to_datalist(infile)
infile.close()
```